# Site and Site Collection features available on SharePoint 2013 install

Tags: 2013, site-collection, site, features

I'm looking for a list of all the Site Features and Site Collection features provided by Microsoft and available on SharePoint 2013 to install.  I did an extensive search and was not able to find any.  All searches are pointing me to currently installed features, but I need the initial set.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Which site collection features are available out of the box in a site collection will depend upon which site template you chose when creating the initial site collection as well as which service applications have an association to the web application hosting the site collection.

So there's no one simple list, the exact features depend on the context of your specific environment. Hence all the other answers and search results just telling you how to get that environment-specific list.

Comment: Thanks @mfoy_.  Is there a way I can get the list of all the site Collection features from Microsoft, regardless of the environment?

Comment: @ManiLive I guess the best way would be to create a clean copy of the environment you intend to check for... although it seems overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell to get list of Installed features.

```
Get-SPFeature -Limit ALL | Where-Object {$_.Scope -eq "SITE"}
```

I believe this will return features irrespective its activated or deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below powershell, it will give you all OOTB feature scoped to Farm, web App, Site and Web. script create a csv and then you can filter it as per your need.

```
$lcid=1033

$delimiter = "*"

Get-SPFeature -Limit ALL | % { Get-SPFeature -Identity $_ | % { $_.DisplayName + $delimiter + $_.GetTitle($lcid) +$delimiter +$_.Scope + $delimiter + $_.Id + $delimiter + $_.GetDescription($lcid)} } >>"C:\Features.csv"
```

[Listing All SharePoint Server 2013 Features – Including Name, Title, Scope, ID and Description](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/razi/archive/2013/10/28/listing-all-sharepoint-2013-features-including-name-title-scope-id-and-description.aspx)